# Regex nested optional groups

Tags: regex

I am trying to capture the bold part of strings like this:

> 1. 'capture a year range at the end of a string **1995-2010**'
> 2. 'if there's no year range just capture the single year  **2005**'
> 3. 'capture a year/year range followed by a parenthesis, including the parenthesis **2007-2012 (58 months)**'

This regex works for 1 and 2, but I can't get it to work for 3:

```
/(\d+([-–— ]\d+( \(\d+ months\))?)?$)/
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Will your strings always be contained in `'`? I mean, are the `'`s part of the string or not?

Comment: What specific regex tool are you using?

Comment: @Aust the `'` is not part of the string. @Glenn I am using this in the context of javascript `.replace()`.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the ANY text in the brackets immediately following the year pattern should be captured, and not just limited to "months" as shown in your example? That is what is being suggested by 3rd line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/\d{4}(?:[-–— ]\d{4})?(?:\s*\([^)]+\))?$/gm
```

This one captures everything in the brackets.
If you need a regex specific to the text "(number) months" in the brackets, then you can use this: `\d{4}(?:[-–— ]\d{4})?(?:\s+\(\d+\smonths\))?$`

Link to test: [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5Cd%7B4%7D%28?%3a%5B-%E2%80%93%E2%80%94%20%5D%5Cd%7B4%7D%29?%28?%3a%5Cs%2a%5C%28%5B%5E%29%5D%2b%5C%29%29?%24&input=capture%20a%20year%20range%20at%20the%20end%20of%20a%20string%201995-2010%0Aif%20there%27s%20no%20year%20range%20just%20capture%20the%20single%20year%202005%0Acapture%20a%20year/year%20range%20followed%20by%20a%20parenthesis,%20including%20the%20parenthesis%202007-2012%20%2858%20months%29%0Atrying%20out%20another%20example%201990%20%2823%20weeks%29%0Atrying%20out%20another%20example%201995-2002%20%28x%20days%29%0Atrying%20out%20another%20example%202050%20%28%28blah%20bl%29%0Atrying%20out%20another%20example%202050%E2%80%943000%0Atrying%20out%20another%20example%202050-3000%0Atrying%20out%20another%20example%202050%E2%80%933000%0A) or [RegExr](http://regexr.com?32282)

Sample text:

- capture a year range at the end of a string 1995-2010
- if there's no year range just capture the single year 2005
- capture a year/year range followed by a parenthesis, including the
  parenthesis 2007-2012 (58 months)
- trying out another example 1990 (23 weeks)
- trying out another example 1995-2002 (x days)
- trying out another example 2050 (blah blah)
- trying out another example 2050—3000
- trying out another example 2050-3000
- trying out another example 2050–3000

And the JavaScript code:

```
var regex = /\d{4}(?:[-–— ]\d{4})?(?:\s*\([^)]+\))?$/gm; //multiline enabled
var input = "your input string"; 
if(regex.test(input)) {
  var matches = input.match(regex);
  for(var match in matches) {
    alert(matches[match]);
  } 
} else {
  alert("No matches found!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a very thorough answer and explanation. This is why I love SO.

Answer (score 2):

This Regex works nicely. :)

```
/(?:(?:\d{4}[-–— ])?\d{4})(?: \(\d+ months\))?$/
```

The main difference between my Regex and Jonah's is that mine contains `?:` which means not to capture the sub-groups. When you group in a Regex it automatically returns what is in that group unless you tell it not to, and I've found that sometimes when those groups get captured when using methods such as `replace` or `split`, that it can be a little buggy which may be your problem as well.

Comment: This one does not seem to match 1 and 2.

Comment: @Kash - Thanks haha it works now. When I copied it, I typo'd the last `?`

Comment: Thanks, this works too—wish I could select more than one answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following regex works for me in a sample Perl script. It should be workable in JavaScript:

```
/(\d{4}([-–— ]\d{4})?( \(\d+ months\))?)$/
```

1. We first match a 4-digit year: `\d{4}`
2. Then we match an optional separator followed by another 4-digit year: `([-–— ]\d{4})?`
3. Finally, we match the optional months portion: `( \(\d+ months\))?`

You may need to insert whitespace matches (`\s*`) where needed, if your data doesn't always follow this strict template.

Comment: The year range can have one of the following delimiters: [-–— ] as suggested by OP's regex. This one does not include that.

Answer (score 0):

It actually works fine here, if I understand your needs correctly: [Gskinner RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?3227j)
Just alternate which sentence is the last, as $ will not count for newlines, just the end of the string.